# Robots.txt to disallow on multi level subdomains

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, robots.txt, multi-subdomains

I've got a server, where I have multiple development projects for clients. While developing, each instance lives on `client.dev.example.com`.

I need to stop crawlers from crawling the development sites.

Is it possible to make a blanket disallow, for all subdomains of `dev.example.com`?

Comment: *Is it possible to make a blanket disallow, for all subdomains of dev.example.com?* Short answer? No. You will need a robots.text file for each and every site.

Answer (score 1):

> While developing, each instance lives on `client.dev.example.com`

Any "polite" bot will request the `robots.txt` file at `http://client.dev.example.com/robots.txt`. So this request must serve the necessary response. There is nothing you can do in a "parent" `robots.txt` file to influence other domains/subdomains, since it's simply never requested for this hostname.

If all your subdomains actually point to the same area of the filesystem then you could simply serve the same `robots.txt` file.

Alternatively, you could have a `robots-disallow.txt` file with each site and conditionally serve this when accessing the dev site, based on the hostname in the request. At least this way you can still distribute the same codebase for the live site without alteration.

For example, in each sites `.htaccess` file, you could do something like the following near the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z-]+\.dev\.
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-disallow.txt [L]
```

This specifically looks for the `.dev.` subdomain (after the `client` subdomain) in the request. If found then it internally rewrites any request for `robots.txt` to `robots-disallow.txt`. Where `robots-disallow.txt` consists of something like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can also have a `robots.txt` file which contains the "live" settings and is only served on the live site (when `.dev.` does not occur in the request).

---

If you have access to the server config, then you could potentially do this once for all sites in the main server config instead of `.htaccess`. You'll need to tweak the `RewriteRule` directive if you do, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots-disallow.txt [L]
```

You could also remove the `robots-disallow.txt` file from each website and store this once elsewhere on your server (providing it is accessible) and rewrite to this file instead (using the absolute filesystem path) - you can only do this in the server config, not `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need include robots.txt for all this dev sites.
Also how crawlers know about your dev sites? Do you have a links to them?
Probably you just need to remove such links

Comment: "how crawlers know about your dev sites?" - It's all too easy for a link to slip out, be shared by a less savvy client etc. etc.